# With MVVM (C# WPF) how do you display settings into their respective controls upon app initialization?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, application-settings

I have 3 comboboxes bound to an object called `ARDAR` with properties `ARFlag`, `DARFlag`, and `ConfirmedFlag`.  When a flag is chosen from a `ComboBox`, its ID is saved in the settings (`Properties.Settings.Default.ARFlag = aRFlag.flag1;`).

When the application starts, an instance of the `ARDAR` object is created via the XAML.  The constructor for the object checks the settings for a non-zero value and updates the property if there is a value (`if (Properties.Settings.Default.ARFlag != 0) ARFlag = sa.flags.Where(f => f.flag1 == Properties.Settings.Default.ARFlag).FirstOrDefault();`)

This triggers the `OnPropertyChanged` method, which I thought would update the comboboxes to then show the selection for the saved setting.  But, upon initializing the application, the comboboxes are left blank.  I made sure that the properties of `ARDAR` are actually being changed to their respective settings and that `OnPropertyChanged` is actually firing.  So, what am I missing? How can I make the ComboBoxes display their saved settings?
Here's my XAML & C# code:

```
       public class ARDAR : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ARDAR()
    {
        var sa = new SALinqDataContext();

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.ARFlag != 0) ARFlag = sa.flags.Where(f => f.flag1 == Properties.Settings.Default.ARFlag).FirstOrDefault();
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.DARFlag != 0) DARFlag = sa.flags.Where(f => f.flag1 == Properties.Settings.Default.DARFlag).FirstOrDefault();
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.ConfirmedFlag != 0) ConfirmedFlag = sa.flags.Where(f => f.flag1 == Properties.Settings.Default.ConfirmedFlag).FirstOrDefault();            
    }

    flag aRFlag;
    flag dARFlag;
    flag confirmedFlag;

    public flag ARFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return aRFlag;
        }

        set
        {
            aRFlag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ARFlag");
            Properties.Settings.Default.ARFlag = aRFlag.flag1;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }

    public flag DARFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return dARFlag;
        }

        set
        {
            dARFlag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DARFlag");
            Properties.Settings.Default.DARFlag = dARFlag.flag1;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }

    public flag ConfirmedFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return confirmedFlag;
        }

        set
        {
            confirmedFlag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConfirmedFlag");
            Properties.Settings.Default.ConfirmedFlag = confirmedFlag.flag1;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }



    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And the relevant XAML:

```
      <Window.Resources>
    <luke:ARDAR x:Key="ARDAR"/>
    <luke:ocSAFlags x:Key="ocSAFlags" />
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Retention">
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Renewals">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource ARDAR}">
                            <Label Content="AR Flag" />
                            <ComboBox Width="120"
                                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource ocSAFlags}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="flag_desc"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding ARFlag}"
                                      />
                            <Label Content="DAR Flag" />
                            <ComboBox Width="120"
                                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource ocSAFlags}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="flag_desc"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DARFlag}" />
                            <Label Content="Conf Flag" />
                            <ComboBox Width="120"
                                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource ocSAFlags}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="flag_desc"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding ConfirmedFlag}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolBar>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Edit: I should also show the code that feeds `ocSAFlags` in case that is relevant to a solution.

```
        public class ocSAFlags : ObservableCollection<flag>
{
    public ocSAFlags()
    {
        var sa = new SALinqDataContext();
        var flags = sa.flags.Where(f => f.available == true)
                        .OrderBy(f => f.flag_desc);
        foreach (flag f in flags) Add(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: SelectedItem="{Binding ARFlag, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: @Steve Good thought, but that didn't work.  I'm thinking the reason it's not updating is because the UI stuff isn't loaded yet at the time `OnPropertyChanged` is called.  I just can't think of a workaround for that.

Comment: Now I know for sure that the UI hasn't loaded yet when `OnPropertyChanged` is called because I attempted to use a static class for `ocSAFlags` with the idea that the `SelectedItem` might have to come from the actual collection as the collection bound to the `ItemsSource`.  I still don't know the answer to THAT, but I did find that I get a 'no constructor' error because of the static class AFTER the OnPropChange has executed. Still stuck.

Comment: most of the time you don't bind directly to a static property

Comment: Any idea on how to update the comboboxes with the data they are bound to after they load?  Or how to delay assignment of said data until after the UI stuff loads?

Comment: i feel like what you did should work if you are not binding to instanced list instead of static one

Comment: It doesn't because the UI doesn't load the content of the controls until after the settings are assigned, which makes sense to me now because the instance of ARDAR must be initialized before any data could be bound to it.  That's why OnPropChanged doesn't trigger the comboboxes to update.  Tomorrow I'm going to try to put the comboboxes inside an `Expander`.  I'm thinking maybe it'll load the values when I expand the expander.  I just don't want the comboboxes to appear 'valueless'  when they do in fact have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that was stopping the `ComboBox` from displaying information ended up having nothing to do with the order in which things load as the program initializes. 
The real problem was that my XAML instantiates an instance of `ocSAFlags` which populates the `ComboBox`, and when `ARDAR` is initialized and sets the value (`flag`) of the bound properties, those values are equivalent but NOT the same actual `flag`. 
So, my solution actually ended up being to make `ocSAFlags` as `Static Class`, and using it to provide a property to serve as the `ItemsSource` for the `ComboBoxes` as well as the 'source' for the linq query that finds the `flag` for the ID stored in settings.

XAML: I removed the line `<luke:ocSAFlags x:Key="ocSAFlags" />` from resources.  I changed ItemsSources: `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static luke:ocSAFlags.OCFlag},Mode=OneWay}"`

And here's the static class:

```
public static class ocSAFlags
{
    static private ObservableCollection<flag> oCFlag = getSAFlags();

    private static ObservableCollection<flag> getSAFlags()
    {
        var x = new ObservableCollection<flag>();
        var sa = new SALinqDataContext();
        var flags = sa.flags.Where(f => f.available == true)
                        .OrderBy(f => f.flag_desc);
        foreach (flag f in flags) x.Add(f);
        return x;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<flag> OCFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return oCFlag;
        }     
    }
}
```